# How can I find the power given only the torque?

Tags: torque, rotation, power

I have a system where I am trying to find the power generated by a DC electric generator. However, I am not very familiar with generators, so I am having difficulty determining the rotational velocity. I have the equation:

torque = Power/2pi * n, where n = revolutions per second.

For convenience, let us say that the torque = 10Nm. I want to find the power, but how can I do that when I do not not how quickly the generator is spinning? Obviously I am missing something, but I'm not sure what it is. Thanks!

Edit: to be a little more specific, given power = 2pi x 1m x 10M x n, where n, I assume, is the number of revolutions per second, can I find the wattage as a real number, not just a symbol?

Comment: You can't calculate power output without the missing information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power is work done per second.  Work is force times distance (if the force vector anf the distance vectors are parallel).  Torque of 10Nm means that at a radius of 1 meter the device can exert a force (in the direction of turn) of 10N.  It can exert that force in a direction parallel to the tangent to a 1m radius circle around the shaft, so over a distance of 2pi x radius, doing work of 2pi x 1m x 10N per revolution.  The power, then, is 2pi x 1m x 10M x n.

Usually a generator *receives* torque rather than *producing* torque.  A motor produces torque.

Comment: Thanks! So, to be a little more specific, given power = 2pi x 1m x 10M x n, where n, I assume, is the number of revolutions per second, can I find the wattage as a real number, not just a symbol?

Comment: Sure.  1 watt = 1 Newton-meter per second.  If you do the multiplication I gave you, the result is in watts.